# Prove the sum of $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt[3]{4}$ is Irrational number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I really don't know how to prove it.
I can prove that $\sqrt[3]{4}$ is irrational and prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.
but as we know , sum of 2 irrational can be irrational or rational ($\sqrt{2} + -\sqrt{2} =$ rational).
so I tried to prove that the sum of 2 different positive irrational numbers is always irrational but also failed.

anyone know?

Comment: The sum of two different positive irrational numbers can be rational, e.g. $\sqrt{2}+(2-\sqrt{2})=2$.

Comment: Yes I know , thats why I failed to prove that the sum of 2 irrational is irrational.

Comment: Hint:  Suppose $\sqrt[3] 4=\alpha-\sqrt 3$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$.  Now cube both sides.

Answer (score 7):

Let $x=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{4}$ so $0=(x-\sqrt{3})^3-4=x^3-3x^2\sqrt{3}+9x-3\sqrt{3}-4$. If $x\in\Bbb Q$, $\sqrt{3}=\frac{x^3+9x-4}{3(x^2+1)}\in\Bbb Q$, a contradiction.

Comment: Wow , never though to mark a random X. Thank you very much. I understood now the technique

Answer (score 0):

The following should allow you to generalize to combinations of a quadratic and a cubic irrational in general:

Every number of the form $\alpha=a+b\sqrt 3$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Q$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial because $(a+b\sqrt3)^2=a^2+3b^2+2ab\sqrt 3$ and so $\alpha$ is a solution of  of
$$X^2-2aX+a^2-3b^2=0. $$
If $\sqrt 3-\sqrt[3]4$ is rational, it follows that the above applies to $\alpha:=\sqrt[3]4$. But we also know that it is a solution of the  $X^3-4=0$. Hence it is also a solution  of
$$ 0=(X^3-4)-(X+2a)\cdot(X^2-2aX+a^2-3b^2)=(\ldots)\cdot X+(\ldots)$$
and therefore rational - contradiction. (Verify that a least one of the "$(\ldots)$" is non-zero!)